# Angular query builder module how to create query for custom date functionality

Tags: angular, angular-material, query-builder

I am trying to create an filter page UI in angular. I am using [angular2-query-builder](https://zebzhao.github.io/Angular-QueryBuilder/) module for this purpose.

For date field I am trying to give expressions along with custom date for filtering purposes. For example, user would have choice to select from multiple options like "Today", "Yesterday", "Tomorrow" and also "Custom-Date". I want to show the date picker, when custom date option is chosen.

Based on the code from the repository - [angular2-query-builder-demo](https://github.com/zebzhao/Angular-QueryBuilder/blob/master/demo/src/app/app.component.ts), if I give options parameter, I am able to give a dropdown to select one of the option. And I am also able to show date picker only when "Custom-Date" option is selected. But I am not able to select a date from the date picker and pass it to the query.

Config object in the component that I have currently:

```
config: QueryBuilderConfig = {
    fields: {
      name: { name: 'Name', type: 'string' },
      notes: { name: 'Notes', type: 'textarea', operators: ['=', '!='] },
      dateCondition: {
        name: 'Date Condition',
        type: 'dateCategory',
        operators: ['=', '<=', '>'],
        options: [
          { name: 'Today', value: 'today' },
          { name: 'Yesterday', value: 'yesterday' },
          { name: 'Custom Date', value: 'customDate'}
        ],
      }
    },
  }
```

Corresponding template code I have is

```
    <ng-container
      *queryInput="
        let rule;
        type: 'dateCategory';
        let options = options;
        let onChange = onChange
      "
    >
      <mat-form-field>
        <mat-select [(ngModel)]="rule.value" (ngModelChange)="onChange()">
          <mat-option *ngFor="let opt of options" [value]="opt.value">
            {{ opt.name }}
          </mat-option>
        </mat-select>
      </mat-form-field>
      <mat-form-field  *ngIf="rule.value=='customDate'">
        <input
          matInput
          [matDatepicker]="picker"
          [(ngModel)]="rule.value"
          (ngModelChange)="onChange()"
        />
        <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
        <mat-datepicker #picker></mat-datepicker>
      </mat-form-field>
    </ng-container>
```

My question is how to propogate the value of the custom date chosen to the query ? I know I am missing something very silly here. But I am not able to figure it out.

Comment: DatePicker selected date is logged to input it is associated with, also there are bunch of events fired by it.

Comment: @Metabolic how to get the datepicker data to get assigned to rule instead of input alone ?

Comment: check my answer for details

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Few things that I see wrong with your code:

1. You are creating variables inside the template and using them and `ngModel`. I am not sure that will work. You need to create models in your component and then use those as ngModels to associate with Angular
2. If you sole purpose is data and template manipulation then you are using Angular the wrong way. You will be better off with [Reactive Forms](https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms)
3. Because of this  `*ngIf="rule.value=='customDate'"` your input will disappear the moment a value gets added to it, provided that you use correct Angular models.

Comment: Hi @Metabolic. Thanks for the help. I actually missed the third point and that caused the issue. The purpose of using query-builder is to create query, so that it can be used in the backend. And regarding the first point, it is the syntax of the query builder component I think.